# Set shipping method per cart item in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

An online shop im working at uses 2 shipping methods: size based rates and local pickup.

The size based rates is the default shipping method, local pickup is only used when a customer clicks **Click and pickup** rather then **Add to cart** (internally, the product is added to the cart in both cases, but when using **Click and pickup**, extra cart item data is added to indicate this).

Calculating the total shipping cost when all cart items are reserved with **Click and pickup** is no problem, since you can filter the shipping rates at runtime with the filter `woocommerce_package_rates` and change the shipping method so it will affect all cart items.

However, if the cart consists of items added with both **Click and pickup** and **add to cart**, it becomes more difficult to calculate the total shipping cost, because the shipping methods must be changed per cart item, and not affect all cart items.

Desired flow:

> **Cart items:** 3 
> Book x 2 *reserved with Click and pickup (cost: 0, local pickup shipping method)*
>
> Paper x 1 *added to cart the normal way,  (cost: default size rates, default shipping method)*
>
> **Total shipping cost:** local pickup cost + default shipping cost

Current code:

```php
function cust_shipping_rates( $rates, $package ) {
   if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

   $product_ids_with_local_pickup = array(); // 'click and pickup'
   
   // Loop through line items
   foreach( $package['contents'] as $line_item ) {
       // Get product id
       $product_id = $line_item['product_id'];
   
       if ( $line_item['sofs_cap'] ) { // indication it's reserved with 'Click and pick'
         array_push($product_ids_with_local_pickup, $product_id);
       }
   }
   
   if ( count($product_ids_with_local_pickup) > 0 ) {
       foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
           if ( in_array( $rate->method_id, array( 'bring_fraktguiden:5800' ) ) ) { // default shipping method
               // how can i exclude the reserved products from being affected by this shipping method?
               $rates[$rate_key]->set_cost(/* cost */); // changing this affects ALL items, not just the specific ones
           }
       }
   }
   
   return $rates;
}

add_filter('woocommmerce_package_rates', 'cust_shipping_rates', 999, 2);
```

Comment: You need to split cart items into shipping packages using `woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages` hook, see [this related threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages) and try to make yourself something.

Comment: Thanks alot! That's the type of filter i was looking for, the one that got iterated through by the shipping rates.

Comment: Welcome! This is not so easy, but it is the right way… If you have any issue with your code, provide it in a new question adding some explanations and details…

Comment: The filter did its job. I only needed a way to exclude some cart items from being calculated towards shipping rates.:)

Comment: You should answer your own question with the code that works for you (with a bit of explanations if needed), as it can help other readers.

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not explain how to add different shipping methods per products, [this plugin](https://woocommerce.com/products/per-product-shipping/) can help with that - however, if you need to exclude certain cart items from being calculated towards shipping cost, this answer might help you.

The filter [woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages/) returns an *package*, containing cart items that the shipping methods in the filter [woocommerce_package_rates](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_package_rates/) iterates over for calculating shipping costs.

Simply remove the cart items you dont wish shipping for by filtering the cart in the returned *package* like this:

```php
// define the woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages callback 
function filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages( $package ) { 
    $new_cart = $package[0]['contents'];

    foreach($cart as $cart_item) {
       // check for desired shipping method
       // cart items not checking for this property, will not be accounted for shipping costs
       if($cart_item['custom_extra_cart_item_data']) {
          array_push($new_cart, $cart_item); 
       } 
    }

    if(!empty($new_cart)) $package[0]['contents'] = $new_cart;

    return $package; 
}; 
         
// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages', 10, 1 );
```

Here is code for my case (the keyname `sofs_cap` is an extra cart item data belonging to a unique cart item, indicating it was added with `click and pick`, your keyname can be whatever you like).

> Note: in my case, i needed at least one shipping method in order to
> checkout. So when the cart consisted of only items not eligible for
> shipping - i simply sat the shipping method to 'Local pickup' (which
> was fitting as well). I also excluded that shipping method when the
> cart had items added both ways.

```php
function custom_shipping_rates($rates, $pkg) {
   if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

   $has_cap = false; // added with click and pikcup
   $has_def = false; // added default way
   
   // Loop through line items
   foreach( $pkg['contents'] as $line_item ) {
      if($line_item['sofs_cap']) $has_cap = true; else $has_def = true;
   }

   $new_rates = array();

   if($has_cap && $has_def || $has_def) { // cart with items added both ways returns all shipping methods except local pickup
      foreach ($rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
         if($rate_key !== 'local_pickup:8') { // id can be different for your shipping method
            $new_rates[$rate_key] = $rate;
         }
     }

     return $new_rates;
   } else if ($has_cap) {  // cart with only items added with Click and pickup returns only shipping method local pickup
      $new_rates['local_pickup:8'] = $rates['local_pickup:8'];
      return $new_rates;
   } 

   return $rates;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_rates', 999, 2);

function custom_filtered_cart_shipping_packages( $shipping_package ) {
    $new_cart = array(); // only contains cart items that are not added with 'Click and pickup'
    $has_cap_added_items = false;
    
    foreach($shipping_package[0]['contents'] as $cart_item) {
        if(!$cart_item['sofs_cap']) {
            array_push($new_cart, $cart_item); // add only default added products to the package
        } else {
            $has_cap_added_items = true;
        }
    }

    $shipping_package[0]['contents'] = $new_cart;
      
    return $shipping_package; 
}
      
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages', 'custom_filtered_cart_shipping_packages');
```